# Let $x \in \mathbb R^k$. Show if there exists a $c \ge 0$ such that $x\cdot y \le c\|y\|, \forall y \in \Bbb R^k$, then $\|x\| \le c$

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

Q1 Can I write this formally as the following implication:

$$\forall y \in \mathbb R^k\; \exists c\ge0:
x\cdot y \le c\|y\| \implies \|x\|\le c$$

Q2 Here is my proof

According to Cauchy-Schwarz

$$
|x \cdot y| \leq\|x\| \cdot\|y\| \iff 
x \cdot y \leq\|x\| \cdot\|y\|
$$

The next observation is a bit hard to explain. I know $ \|x\| \ge 0, \forall x$ and $c \ge 0$.  So i just substitute $x$ with $c$ in the last inequality: $x \cdot y \leq c\|y\|$. But I do not know how to do formulate the last step (the conclusion) that it implies $\|x\|\le c$.

NB: I'm doing an introductory course on real analysis.

Comment: Take $y=x$ and conclude

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch why ?

Comment: (Remark: Before I suggested an indirect proof but after the edit I suggest a direct proof) Indeed with $y=x$, you get $\|x\|^2\le c \|x\|$, can you take it from here?

Comment: Sorry, did not see you edit. Thanks. you could submit it as an answer so I can accept

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $\|x\|>c$ and $y=x.$ (It said for ALL values of $y;$ thus is must be true in particular when $y=x.$)

Then you have $x\cdot y = x\cdot x = \|x\|^2 > c\|x\|.$